# Two general questions regarding intervals in $\mathbf{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

- Does an open interval contain infinitely many closed intervals?
- Is the interval $(-1,1)$ equal to $[-a,a]$ where $a<1$? Why?

Comment: A closed interval $[a,b]$ is always infinite unless $a=b$, in which case it contains just one point, or $a>b$, in which case it’s empty. Did you mean *infinitely **many** closed intervals*?

Comment: Yes, infinitely many closed intervals.

Comment: For the first, you can even get infinitely many disjoint closed intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT for the second question: If $a<1$, then $a<\frac12(a+1)<1$.

**Added:** For the first question, let $(a,b)$ be a non-empty closed interval. Pick any $x\in(a,b)$. Consider the intervals $[c,x]$ for $c\le x<b$.

Comment: I am sorry, but could you elaborate more on the hint for the second question? I don't think I really understand it.

Comment: @user97554: It’s a **very** big hint as it stands; I’m not sure what more I can say without simply telling you the answer. Let’s see; if $x>a$, is $x\in[-a,a]$?

Answer (score 1):

No. $(-1,1)$ equal to the **union** of all intervals of the form $(-a,a)$ for $a < 1$. In other words $\displaystyle \bigcup _{a < 1} (-a, a) = (-1,1)$. There cannot exist a fixed $a$ such that $[-a,a] = (-1,1)$, since if $a < 1$ we have $a < \displaystyle \frac{a+1}{2} < 1$ and so $ \displaystyle \frac{a+1}{2} \in (-1,1)$ but $\displaystyle \frac{a+1}{2} \notin [-a,a]$.